# SQL Server ODBC connection with Kerberos/AD Authentication

Tags: sql-server, odbc, kerberos

I have SQL Server that uses Kerberos authentication on my company's network. I am trying to setup a Linux system to be able to access that SQL Server using pyodbc. I am new to Kerberos, but have been able to get my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) box working with Kerberos... Atleast thats what I think. I can do `kinit <username>` and it recognizes my username and password.

What do I do next?

If I do this:

```
sqlcmd -S MyDatabase.corp.com
```

I get this:

```
sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: Cannot find KDC for realm "COMPANYNET.CORP.COM".
```

I am pretty sure I am just not doing the next step but I haven't found a good source to tell me what to do next. Any help is much appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much headache and annoying a lot of people at my company I got this to finally work.

1. Had to get a Service Account setup on the Domain
2. Had to get a krb5.keytab file made by an AD Admin
3. Had to setup Kerberos with the correct Domain in my /etc/krb5.conf file
4. Had to have SPNs set for the target SQL Server (This seems to be the actual cause of the above error message)
5. Ensure proper permissions set Service Account on SQL Server.

Once above was set I can do:

```
kinit -k <SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>
sqlcmd -E -S MyDatabase.corp.com
```